# Microsoft SC VMM 2008 R2 doesn't have option to compact virtual hard disk

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, vhd, scvmm, shrink

I can't figure out how to shrink a VHD using Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2. Viewing the article [Shrink your VHD size](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chengw/archive/2009/01/07/shrink-your-vhd-size.aspx) seems like this would be simple to do. However I don't see any of those check boxes that article shows.

The article does mention that all check points need deleted first, I have followed that information and deleted the check points.

Here's what I see [image]

Comment: Not an answer, but that article is from SCVMM 2008, yours looks like 2008 R2 (which was released in 2010, go figure)

Comment: So they removed features from release -> R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between yesterday and this morning 2 things occurred inside of SC VMM without any interaction from myself:

1. the check boxes that weren't visible appeared in the virtual machine properties.
2. the amount of disk allocated to the machine I wanted to compact decreased by almost half.

Combining this observation with information I read yesterday that deleting check points is a slow process, it appears that I had deleted the check points but they weren't physically deleted. That at any point a VHD has check points in any state it disables access to these disk controls.

Comment: Deleted checkpoints only merge while the machine is off and it's an incredibly slow process (typically in the order of a few GB/h).

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a limitation in terms of the IDE virtualization. If a hard drive is on the IDE adapter, the virtual machine must be stopped before any changes to the hard disk can be made.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353280.aspx

The reason you're not seeing the options is probably because the VM is running.

Here's a screenshot of my VM properties of a running VM with IDE as the storage configuration.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The machine is absolutely stopped.

Comment: You got it right, when theres snapshots involved you loose access to those options until the snapshots are finished applying.

Comment: +1, Unfortunately VMM hides options that aren't currently available (instead of graying them out), so there's something preventing you from compacting (running VM, snapshots, not a dynamic VHD, etc).

Comment: You may also want to consider migrating (carefully) to a SCSI interface inside your VM. It'll allow you the ability to hot-swap virtual drives, etc. Something on my to-do list as well.